# PHP array by reference persists

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have encountered something strange, an hope someone can explain what's happening. I've boiled it down to the following case for reproducing on PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21:

```
$lines = array("foo" => "bar");

foreach ($lines as &$line) { } // Trouble-causer

$temp = $lines;

foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    $lines[$key] = "test";
}
print_r($lines);
print_r($temp);
```

The expected result of this, since I'm not working on `$temp`, is

```
Array
(
    [foo] => test
)
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

But the actual result is

```
Array
(
    [foo] => test
)
Array
(
    [foo] => test
)
```

If I remove the line marked `Trouble-causer` it works as expected. Somehow the fact that I cycled `$lines` items by reference persists into the next iteration. Is this to be expected?

Comment: your actual result is irrelevent since you have the same key 2 times !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) say:

> **Warning** Reference of a `$value` and the last array element remain even
>   after the `foreach` loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`.

```
foreach ($lines as &$line) { } // Trouble-causer
unset($line);
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that bit. Very strange behavior, though, but at least now I'm aware of it.